# Apply foreign key (Brand) into the User Brand object

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue with the following line: `user_brand = UserBrand(user=user, brand=serializers)`, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeansymolanza/projects/adsoma-api/api/views.py", line 137, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeansymolanza/projects/adsoma-api/api/views.py", line 154, in create
    user_brand = UserBrand(user=user, brand=serializers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 439, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 207, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<module 'rest_framework.serializers' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py'>": "UserBrand.brand" must be a "Brand" instance.
```

All I want to do is apply the foreign key (*Brand*) into the **User Brand** object.

**views.py**

```
class BrandSignup(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Brand signup
    HTTP POST
    """
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSignupSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if User.objects.filter(email=request.data['email']).exists():
            response_details = {
                'data': "",
                'message': "This email account is already in use. Please try using another one.",
                'code': "400",
                'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
                user = User(email=request.data['email'], password=request.data['password'],
                            account_type=request.data['account_type'])
                user.save()
                user_brand = UserBrand(user=user, brand=serializer)
                user_brand.save()
                response_details = {
                    'data': request.data,
                    'message': "Account created successfully.",
                    'code': "201",
                    'status': HTTP_201_CREATED
                }
            else:
                response_details = {
                    'data': serializer.errors,
                    'message': "Your account cannot be created at this moment in time. Please try again later.",
                    'code': "400",
                    'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
```

**models.py**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    """
    Brand model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Brands"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.brand


class UserBrand(models.Model):
    """
    User brand model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Brands"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.user, self.brand)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass a `BrandSignupSerializer` object to the `UserBrand` constructor as the `brand`...  You need a `Brand` object instead.  You should be able to fix this by replacing your line with

```
user_brand = UserBrand(user=user, brand=serializer.instance)
```